# A proof that BS(1,2) is not polycyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

I am looking for examples of finitely generated solvable groups that are not polycyclic. In [Wikipedia](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_solvable_not_implies_polycyclic#Some_examples_based_on_the_general_construction_and_otherwise) Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,2)$ is an example. But how to prove this fact?

Answer (score 6):

For a polycyclic group, every subgroup is finitely generated, in particular the commutator subgroup is finitely generated. Now assume that $BS(1,2)$ is  polycyclic. Hence its derived subgroup is finitely generated. However, the derived subgroup is isomorphic to the group of $2$-adic rationals, i.e., the group of all rationals with denominators powers of $2$. This group is not finitely generated, a contradiction.

More generally, all Baumslag-Solitar groups $BS(1,m)$ for $m\ge 2$ are metabelian, but not polycyclic, because the commutator subgroup $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{m}]$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: Just to be picky :) ... Aren't polycyclic groups always finitely generated?

Comment: You are right - I have corrected it, thank you.

Comment: thanks, but how to find the derived subgroup of $BS(1,2)$?

Comment: The derived subgroup of $BS(1,m)=\langle a,b \mid bab^{-1}=a^m \rangle$ is the normal subgroup generated by $a$. This is $\mathbb{Z}[1/m]$, because $BS(1,m)\simeq \mathbb{Z}[1/m] \ltimes \mathbb{Z}$ - see below.

Answer (score 3):

The Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1, 2) = \mathbb{Z} \ltimes \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ under the isomorphism $a \to (0, 1), b \to (1, 0)$, where the generator $g$ of the left term acts by $g.1 = 2$. But $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]\subset BS(1, 2)$ is clearly not finitely generated, so $BS(1, 2)$ is not polycyclic.

Comment: Can you please write more explanations on how $(a,b|bab^{-1}=a^{2})=BS(1, 2) = \mathbb{Z} \ltimes \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: Use the presentation to show that every element of $BS(1, 2)$ is of the form  $a^n b^m$.